# How do I continuously execute my script for sending mails?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, php-7.2

I want my part of my Magento code to continuously execute.
For example: 
If I want to send mail for those customers who have not ordered any product from last 3 month.
So in this case i have to find mail triggering timings for them.

Consider 
A customer have  not ordered and its 3 months completed on particular day on morning
And B customer have not ordered and its 3 months completed on same day(as A customer) in evening

How can I do in such condition?

I expect the output 
For A customer's mail send on morning 
And For B customer's mail send on evening

Comment: For sending email you can create cronjob in Magento where you can set code for find customers and send email (can create 2 cron for morning & evening or can set as 12hr interval)